# Asp.Net MVC Routing with Subviews

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a controller "Home" and 2 actions inside it called "DeliveryReturn" and one called "BasketReturn" like this:

```
public ActionResult DeliveryReturn(string id)
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult BasketReturn(string id)
{
    return View();
}
```

- ".../Home/Return/Delivery/10" -> DeliveryReturn should be called.
- ".../Home/Return/Basket/10" -> BasketReturn should be called.

I tried setting up my route somewhat like this. I am really lost though and it seems like it doesn't make sense at all.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Return",
    url: "Home/Return/{type}/{id}",
);
```

**Update:**

I figured it out, that I could do something like this. However, this would require me to register two routings. How would I do it with only one?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DeliveryReturn",
    url: "Home/Return/Delivery/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "DeliveryReturn", id= ""}
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BasketReturn",
    url: "Home/Return/Basket/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "BasketReturn", id= ""}
);
```